# efficient comparison of list of ints with a given int in C++

Tags: c++

Is there an efficient/elegant way to compare a list of ints with a given int in C++. Lets say I have a quartet of numbers: P, Q, R, S and I need to compare them with a given int T to get different case scenarios.

`if (P == T && Q != T && R != T && S != T) case('P');
 else if (P != T && Q == T && R != T && S != T) case('Q');
 else if (P != T && Q != T && R == T && S != T) case('R');
 else if (P != T && Q != T && R != T && S == T) case('S');`

Similarly I will have 6 paired cases: PQ, QR, PR ..., 4 triplet cases and 1 quartet case. As you can see, lot of explicit comparisons! Is there an elegant way to do this using STL containers?

I need one of these cases as my output: 'P', 'Q', .., 'PQ', 'RS',.. 'PQR', 'PQS'... 'PQRS'. I plan to do a switch-case as all these combinations will invoke different codes.

Comment: @StoryTeller Otherwise the comparison operator could solve an issue regarding comparisons indeed. :-D

Comment: An integer can have only one value at a time. If `T` is equal to `P`, there's no need to check it's also not equal to `Q`, `R` and `S`. Unless you are trying to get a reward from the redundant department of redundancy.

Comment: What is the *actual* problem you have? *Why* do you want this comparison? Please read about [the XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/) and think about how it relates to your question (asking about help for a solution to an unknown problem).

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I need all the combinations naturally from the comparison, it should be able to give either of the 15 cases. @StoryTeller let me get back to you in a while

Comment: every combination could be potentially unique as far as my code is concerned

Comment: @StoryTeller probably OP is comparing some quantum state?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a lookup map with a Boolean-tuple as key:

```
std::map<std::tuple<bool,bool,bool,bool>,value> map;
```

Looking up the value is then simply something like this:

```
map.find({T==P,T==Q,T==R,T==S});
```

(wrap this in a lookup function to make it easier of course).

The value of the map will be determined what you actually need.  It can be a string, a numeric value, or even an std::function (lambda) to be executed if the key is found.

Alternatively you can also use an unordered_map, but then you need to provide a hash-function yourself as STL has no default hash-function for tuples.

Comment: Thanks! It looks like defining a suitable function for the value of the map can solve my problem.

Comment: This has the disadvantage that you will always perform all the comparisons.

Comment: @rubenvb: which is also needed.  The question states that all compares must be executed in order to find which action is to be executed.  Suppose that I ask you to pick 4 random numbers without telling me what they are, they don't have to be all different.  Then I pick one number and I tell you you get 100$ from me for every number that is right.  You will have to compare all of your 4 numbers with my number.  If I make the problem more complex (e.g. if the first number is right you get 10$, if the second is right you get 25$, ...) then you get exactly the original problem.

Comment: I agree with @Patrick here. We need 4 comparisons at the least for every quartet of (P,Q,R,S) as the state of the quartet could be any of the 2^4 cases and since each state has the same probability.

Answer (score 3):

You could use bitwise operations to combine the results of the four tests into a single `0..15` integer value. Note that each comparison is only performed once.

Once you have the resulting value it can be used as an index into an array or `std::vector` or a key lookup into an associative container. I've used a `switch` with the result in this simple example.

```
int mask = (P == T) << 3 | (Q == T) << 2 | (R == T) << 1 | (S == T);

switch (mask) // 0..15
{
    case 15: // PQRS
        break;
    case 14: // PQR
        break;
    case 13: // PQS
        break;
    case 12: // PQ
        break;
    case 11: // PRS
        break;
    case 10: // PR
        break;
    case 9: // PS
        break;
    case 8: // P
        break;
    case 7: // QRS
        break;
    case 6: // QR
        break;
    case 5: // QS
        break;
    case 4: // Q
        break;
    case 3: // RS
        break;
    case 2: // R
        break;
    case 1: // S
        break;
    case 0: // none
        break;
}
```

Comment: Smart.  To improve it even further, use a vector where the value determines what to do (e.g. an std::function).  In that sense, the solution is similar to what I proposed, using an unsorted_map.

Answer (score 2):

Try matching a bit-field.

If we consider a 4 bit-field 0000 we can set the first bit if `T==P` the second if `T==Q` and so on:

```
unsigned index{(P==T?1U:0U)|(Q==T?2U:0U)|(R==T?4U:0U)|(S==T?8U:0U)};
```

Then just index into an array.

NB 1: I notice another answer using the same trick with a `switch` which will also work.

NB 2: You can regard this implementation as a hash-table using a 'perfect hash'.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

//Actual Solution Starts Here.

const std::string match_data[] {
 "",//0000
 "P",//0001
 "Q",//0010
 "PQ",//0011
 "R",//0100
 "PR",//0101
 "PQ",//0101
 "PQR",//0111
 "S",//1000
 "PS",//1001
 "QS",//1010
 "PQS",//1011
 "RS",//1100
 "PRS",//1101
 "PQS",//1101
 "PQRS"//1111
};


std::string match(int T, int P, int Q, int R, int S){
    unsigned index{(P==T?1U:0U)|(Q==T?2U:0U)|(R==T?4U:0U)|(S==T?8U:0U)};
    return match_data[index];
}

//Actual Solution Ends Here.

//The rest is a trivial test harness...

bool error{false};

int check(int T, int P, int Q, int R, int S, const std::string& expect){
    const auto result{match(T,P,Q,R,S)};
    if(result!=expect){
        std::cout<<"Error ("<<T<<','<<P<<','<<Q<<','<<R<<','<<S<<")=="<<result<<"!="<<expect<<std::endl;
        error=true;
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}


int main() {
    int errors{0};

    errors+=check(7,1,2,3,4,"");
    errors+=check(7,7,2,3,4,"P");
    errors+=check(9,1,9,3,4,"Q");
    errors+=check(117,1,6,117,4,"R");
    errors+=check(13,1,7,3,13,"S");
    errors+=check(132,132,132,132,132,"PQRS");
    errors+=check(98,98,98,3,4,"PQ");
    errors+=check(9876,56,87,9876,4,"R");
    errors+=check(1,1,0,1,0,"PR");
    errors+=check(78,78,78,78,0,"PQR");

    if(errors==0&&!error){
        std::cout<<"Success"<<std::endl;
    }else{
        std::cout<<"ERRORS: "<<errors<<std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Also, kudos for explaining the logic so clearly.